# Как происходит группировка посредством выражений?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_year) year, COUNT(*) how_many 
  FROM employee 
 GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date);
```

Как тут работает группировка?

Comment: Сначала extract выделяет год, а потом group by собирает в одну группу все записи с одинаковым годом. Правда на выводе у вас год из другого поля, mysql это позволяет, но применяет правило "первый попавшийся" в итоге вы можете увидеть совсем не те года, по которым отработал group by

Comment: ничего не понял

Comment: тогда поясните ваш вопрос. я ответил на столько на сколько его понял. И скажите почему у вас в select extract выделяет год из поля start_year, а в group by год берется из поля start_date ? Там половина ответа собственно об этом

Comment: GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date);
вот как сработает эта часть запроса?

Comment: точно так же, как если бы у вас в таблице была отдельная колонка year в которой бы лежал год из start_date. Т.е. выдаст суммарные строки по одной на каждый год

Comment: все равно не дошло
еще попытка
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date)
насколько я понял функция возвратит столбец с годами и я не пойму как это влияет на группировку
чем оно отличается если указать в группировке название столбца по которому хотим сгруппировать?
то есть в обычной группировке я указываю столбец по которому хочу сгруппировать и я знаю что все повторяющиеся строки будут объеденены в одну, а в этом указывается функция которая возвратит строки с годами и как эта группировка работает не пойму.

Comment: то есть GROUP BY start_date (если бы возвращался год например 2009) эквивалентен GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date)? т.к. в первом тоже возвращаются строки с датами

Comment: Предполагается что в start_date же разные даты за один год. Если сделать group by по ней то вы получите отдельные строки для 1 января 2009 года и для 2 января, и так далее по одной строке для каждого числа. А так как extract возвращает только год, то вы получите только 1 общую строку для всех дат в этом году.